# Conditional Insertion of Record Into MYSQL table Using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form set up for inserting records into a table using PHP and MYSQL. There are 2 fields responsible for capturing datetimes, which I will use to represent a time span. Here is the code I am using to insert the records:

```
    if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form1")) {
  $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO song_of_the_day (id, station, song_title, artist, start_date, end_date, start_listenhour, end_listenhour) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['id'], "int"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['station'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['song_title'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['artist'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString(date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($_POST['startDay'] . $_POST['start-hour'] . ':' . $_POST['start-minute'] . $_POST['start-meridian'])), "date"),
                       GetSQLValueString(date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($_POST['endDay'] . $_POST['end-hour'] . ':' . $_POST['end-minute'] . $_POST['end-meridian'])), "date"),
                       GetSQLValueString(date("H:i:s", strtotime($_POST['start_listenhour-hour'] . ':' . $_POST['start_listenhour-minute'] . $_POST['start_listenhour-meridian'])), "date"),
                       GetSQLValueString(date("H:i:s", strtotime($_POST['end_listenhour-hour'] . ':' . $_POST['end_listenhour-minute'] . $_POST['end_listenhour-meridian'])), "date"));

  mysql_select_db($database_mysqlconnect, $mysqlconnect);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $mysqlconnect) or die(mysql_error());

  $insertGoTo = "manage.php?mess=3";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
    $insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  }
  header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));
}

mysql_select_db($database_mysqlconnect, $mysqlconnect);
$query_Recordset1 = "SELECT * FROM song_of_the_day";
$Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1, $mysqlconnect) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);
$totalRows_Recordset1 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset1);
```

If I have an entry that is made which falls within that time span, I would consider that a duplicate entry and would like the form to INSERT or REPLACE based on that. I would like to use the following to incorporate into my application, but am stuck as to what to do next:

```
    $get_startdate = GetSQLValueString(date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($_POST['startDay'] . $_POST['start-hour'] . ':' . $_POST['start-minute'] . $_POST['start-meridian'])), "date");
    $get_enddate = GetSQLValueString(date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($_POST['endDay'] . $_POST['end-hour'] . ':' . $_POST['end-minute'] . $_POST['end-meridian'])), "date");
    $get_station = GetSQLValueString($_POST['station'], "text");
    $query = "SELECT * FROM song_of_the_day WHERE station = '$get_station' start_date <= CURDATE() AND end_date >= '$get_enddate'";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
    $get_id = $row['id'];
    $warning = 'onClick="Warning! An entry is already scheduled to display during this time span. Do you want to overwrite the entry?"';
    }
    else{
    $warning = null;
    }
```

How do I incorporate the latter code here with the original to achieve the conditional INSERT/REPLACE for my form?

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Make **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will end up with severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Is this Dreamweaver-generated code? If so, stop using the junk that it spews out. It's wickedly out of date. You can use any PHP database layer you want, you're not stuck using that `GetSQLValueString` nonsense.

Comment: You couldn't be more spot on with your assumptions of my situation. I just don't have the time to learn PHP in a chapter-by-chapter approach, so I always find myself just trying to figure out how to do something based on a combination of tutorials and built-in Dreamweaver wizards. It's not a very effective or efficient approach. Thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: If you're looking to do a lot of PHP development work I'd strongly suggest you have a look at the various [development frameworks](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) available today. They give you a much better foundation for building applications than the core PHP library. [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) is a particularly good example, it's well documented, it has plenty of useful examples, and there's many [quick introductions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/quickstart) that walk you through the basics.

Comment: Laravel offers a very simple way to achieve this.